# function is not found when instantiate a template function in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

It might be a stupid question but I totally don't have any idea about the prompt.

The code is in a .cpp file

```
template <typename T> void foo2(T){}
template void foo2<int>(int);
```

VS2017 keeps telling me that: Function definition for function 'foo2' is not found. However, the code actually works in VS2017, no error message if I run it. I don't know if it is an IDE-specific problem or it is the code problem. As it is quite annoying, does anyone know why the prompt appears and how to fix it? Thanks!

=========Update===========

Here is the full code(Move the instantiation to .h file but still have the same problem):

test.h

```
#pragma once
template <typename T> void foo2(T);
template void foo2<int>(int);
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
template <typename T>void foo2(T){}
```

main file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    foo2(a);
}
```

I tend to believe that an IDE-specific question. If I ask VS to show the potential fix, it will create the following code in .cpp file:

```
template void foo2(int)
{
    return template void();
}
```

which is definitely wrong. Even cannot pass the compilation.

Comment: Is `foo2` forward declared? Templates need to be fully defined before they're instantiated, so that the compiler knows how to instantiate at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did the declaration in the corresponding .h file and the header has been included in the .cpp file. The main function is in a separate .cpp files and foo2's .h is included. These three are the only files in the project. In fact, even if I put the instantiation in the .h file, I will get the same prompt. I asked VS to fix it, VS will create an empty function definition for it. I don't understand how this could happen..

Comment: Please include all your files in the question to help illustrate. Your full template _definition_ needs to be available _in_ or _included from_ the header file.

Comment: The code is OK, the IDE is acting funny. Ask Microsoft to fix it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the actual error message is different. MSVC may have some minor issues with templates, but it 100% certainly knows that `foo2` is **not** a function, so it won't complain that its definition can't be found. Now `foo2<int>` is a function missing a definition, so I can see MSVC complain about that.

Comment: @alterigel I have posted all the code, it gives me the same prompt even I instantiate the template in .h file. The potential fix from VS is also posted. Thx.

Comment: @MSalters Well, if that is the case, it is hard for me to believe they can make the instantiation of the template class correct...

Answer (score 0):

With the expanded code, I get the idea.

You actually want `extern template void foo2<int>(int);` in the .h file. There should be only one instantiation, in test.cpp. `extern template` is new in C++11, so while your book might not yet cover it it's certainly understood by VS2017.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your suggestion, but got the same prompt. So sad it does not work. I have reported it to MS. Let's see how they will respond.